# how to make dynamic expandable cell, height according to content,of UItableView using Xib

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

[image: cell without expand]

I want to make this kind of cell, which contain variable height according to address length below the time "5:30", i want to make this kind of cell using xib.

Second thing : when user click on cell area the cell is expanded and all other fields become visible.
I want to make this all by using xib

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can do it by setting up dynamic height of UITableView Cell,

in your Tableview cell heightForRowAtIndexPath event use following code to return custom height as per text,

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    NSString *text;
   text = @"You can pass your text here";

    CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(300, 20000.0f);

    CGSize size = [text sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica neue" size:13.0] constrainedToSize:constraint lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

    CGFloat height = size.height;//MAX(size.height, 44.0f);

    return height;
}
```

and in your cell for row at index path set the your label height where you want to display address,

```
  NSString *text = @"your text of address goes here";
  CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(cell.lblAddress.frame.size.width, 20000.0f);
    CGSize size = [text sizeWithFont:cell.lblAddress.font constrainedToSize:constraint lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
    CGFloat height = size.height;
    CViewSetY(cell.lblAddress, 0);
    CViewSetHeight(cell.lblAddress, height);
    [cell.lblAddress setNumberOfLines:0];
```